# Implementing graph cut on image using Energy function

Tags: image-processing, graph, image-segmentation, max-flow

I was trying to extract the hair from a given image as described in the [research paper](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/tswj/2014/748634/), using the concept of energy minimisation, The energy function is dependent on both Prior probability and YCrCb colour likelihood histogram. The energy function is defined as:

```
(x)= data(x)+smooth(x).
```

> data (x)=−∑(log(I(x)|x)+logsel (x))  **[Prior probability model]**
>
> smooth (x) = ∑ (x ≠x )exp(-||(x)−(x)||^2/)  **[Prior YcrCb color model]**

I am confused at how to label the given graph(pixels of the images are treated as nodes of graph). I tried to label the graph using the following approach but the results are not as expected:

```
def get_Edata(prob_dist, ycrcb_dist, img_y, img_x, pix):
    e_data = 0
    Y, Cr, Cb = pix
    if ycrcb_dist[int(Y/4)][int(Cr/4)][int(Cb/4)] > 0 and prob_dist[img_y][img_x]>0:
        e_data = -1*(math.log(ycrcb_dist[int(Y/4)][int(Cr/4)][int(Cb/4)], 10) + math.log(prob_dist[img_y][img_x], 10))
    return e_data


def get_ESmooth(normalization_constant, pix_1, pix_2):
    return math.exp(-(math.ceil(pix_1[0] - pix_2[0])**2)/normalization_constant)
```

And while adding weight between the nodes in graph I use:

```
#adding the edges between neighbouring pixels.
img_graph.add_edge(central_node, neighbour_nodes, eSmooth, 0)
#adding the edges from source to node and from node to sink.
img_graph.add_tedge(central_node, weight_source, max_val_weight-source)
```

I guess the issue is with the `max_val_weight-source` because changing the value to some lower integer gives me relatively good results but that is not the right way of doing it.

Also changing the value of eSmooth to 0 doesn't affects the output?

I would highly appreciate if someone could shed some light on this context.

Comment: please format your question to be more readable / human friendly so you can get good answers.